# Solución Error over flow necesito plotear mas puntos usando la función de ploteo contourf

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

tengo 8.000 puntos de un levantamiento topográfico con coordenadas x, y, z.
el programa me emite el error `OverflowError: In draw_path_collection: Exceeded cell block limit`

```
X=datos.iloc[0:dats,0].values
Y=datos.iloc[0:dats,1].values
Z=datos.iloc[0:dats,2].values
xi,yi= np.meshgrid(X,Y)
zi = griddata((X,Y),Z,(xi,yi),method='cubic')
plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,extend='both',vmin=dt_bar[0],vmax=dt_bar[-1],
                cmap=cmap)
```

**Nota**: ya he usado el comando `mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 20000`
pero no me ha dado ninguna solucion esto

Comment: Esta es una pregunta más de fondo: ¿Necesitás realmente mostrar tal cantidad de puntos? lo pregunto por que dependiendo del medio tal vez ni siquiera lleguen a apreciarse.

Comment: la verdad son unos puntos tomados en campo con topgrafia seria útil tratar de ubicar la mayor cantidad posible